# Invoking Link in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an href taged object (graphic) on a page that I want to programatically click on.  However,I can't figure out how to reference the object.  Here is the tag:

```
<div id="getthebutton">
    <div>
        <a onmouseout="MM_swapImage('btn123','','http://www.comp.com/img/btn_img.png',1)" onmousedown="MM_swapImage('btn123','','http://www.comp.com/img/buttons/btn_inv.png',1)" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('btn123','','http://www.comp.com/img/buttons/btn_inv.png',1)" href="javascript:do_activity("param1", 1);">
            <img id="btn123" width="180" height="60" alt="" src="http://www.comp.com/img/buttons/other_btn.png"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I click on this thing?  If I read this right "btn123" is just an image file.

Comment: You href looks invalid you use the same quotation marks inside the javascript where you should use apostrophes.

Comment: Indeed. **Don't use javascript: URLs**. Ever. Seriously.

Comment: DHTML image swapping is oldschool.  jQuery will handle all your needs.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically click on that you would have to do something like this

```
$("a").click();
```

Of course it helps to have an event handler assigned first, but it is really that simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Using parentNode will give you access to the <a> tag, but I don't know if that helps you, cause I'm not sure what exactly you are doing.

```
document.getElementById("btn123").parentNode
```

I believe in jQuery, it is parent():

```
$('#btn123').parent()
```

So you could probably do:

```
$('#btn123').parent().click()
```

Comment: The parent().click() doesn't seem to work unless I am doing something wrong

Comment: Yes, from what I understand, click only works if you have bound a click function to the item.  Can you just call "do_activity("param1", 1);"?, or do you not know what this is?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should really listen to the comments (javascript: links == dark side).  That being said ...

```
$("div#getthebutton div a").click();
```

Comment: Listening, but I am not in control of the source javascript/HTML...I didn't write it.

Comment: Didn't realize that.  You could try using the raw Javascript stuff instead.  For IE this would be something like $("div#getthebutton div a").get(0).fireEvent("onclick"), whereas for Firefox (and others) you'd use createEvent (which is a little more complicated so I won't provide an example, but you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the anchor has a javascript href-value. Understanding that you have no control over the source, your only other option would be to evaluate the value of the HREF:

```
// run the href-javascript from the parent anchor
eval($("#btn123").parent().attr("href"));
```

Invoking a click from the code will not invoke the javascript code. As such, you must evaluate it instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the *result* of clicking on the image, from the code I would say your JavaScript should simply be:

```
do_activity("param1", 1);
```

That's what ultimately happens when the image is clicked by a human. This bypasses the 'click' events, so you might miss out on some side-effects, but it's what I'd try first.